# Unable to import CSV data into Cloud SQL database

Tags: postgresql, csv, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sql

I am following [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/importing#csv) article and trying to import data from `CSV` file to `Cloud SQL` database but getting error

```
$ gcloud sql import csv cloud-ks gs://ks_bucket/ks_data.csv --database=ks-db --table=ks_tb

ERROR: (gcloud.sql.import.csv) [ERROR_RDBMS] ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "Nikhil"
CONTEXT:  COPY ks_tb, line 1, column user_id: "Nikhil"
```

**Command to create table**

```
CREATE TABLE ks_tb (user_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, username VARCHAR(255), col1 float8, col2 float8, col3 float8, col4 float8, col5 float8, target VARCHAR(255));
```

**ks_data.csv**

[image]

Comment: Error is indicating that schema on your table on GCP is not matching what you are trying to upload. Like first column on table in GCP seems to be integer but in csv file it is text 'Nikhil'

Comment: @SmartCoder `user_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY` should generate data (unique number) for column 1 automatically

Comment: I think bulk import is involved here. In that case, DB will not create serial number. You will have to provide the same

Comment: @SmartCoder Ok I will give it a try

Comment: @arush1836 can you please post the answer for visibility if the problem got resolved ?